# How to get correct current URL in JSP in Spring webapp

Tags: spring, jsp, url, web-applications, request

I'm trying to get a correct current URL in JSP in Spring webapp. I'm trying to use the following fragment in the JSP file:

```
${pageContext.request.requestURL}
```

The issue is that the returned URL contains prefix and suffix defined by UrlBasedViewResolver. For example the correct URL is:

http://localhost:8080/page

But the returned one is:

http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/jsp/page.jsp

Comment: Do you need the absolute URL? Or you just want to build a internal link to another page in your application?

Comment: I need the absolute URL.

Answer (score 53):

The best way would be to use [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) like this:

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. It returns the current action URL without the base URL and query strings.

Comment: This does not work. It does not return the absolute URL.as requested by the OP in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 8):

In a `jsp` file:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

Comment: Does not return an absolute URL as requested by the OP in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you are looking for something like:

```
<%= new UrlPathHelper().getOriginatingRequestUri(request) %>
```

This is not that elegant but solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can make Interceptor and set request attribute e.g.

```
  request.setAttribute("__SELF",request.getRequestURI);
```

and in jsp

```
  <form action="${__SELF}" ></form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Anyone who wants to know about other than the reuqest URI, for example a query string, you can check all the names of the variables in the code of [`RequestDispatcher`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.java)(of Servlet API 3.1+) interface.

You can get the query string like this:

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just found the right answer for your question. The key is using Spring Tags.

```
<spring:url value="" />
```

If you put the value attribute empty, Spring will display the mapping URL set in your @RequestMapping.

Comment: It doesn't display anything in my case :/

Comment: I believe the browser will use the current URL when the target is empty. Does the server/webapp also?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpUtils.*" %>
<%= javax.servlet.http.HttpUtils.getRequestURL(request) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, please edit with the nondepercated option.

Comment: @MUYBelgium Have you tried opening a separate Stack-Overflow question ? I wish I had more time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Which Spring version are you using?  I have tested this with Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, using the following simple application:

```
Folder structure
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

spring-web
    |
     --- src
          |
           --- main
                 |
                  --- webapp
                         |
                          --- page
                         |     |
                         |      --- home.jsp
                         |
                          --- WEB-INF
                               |
                                --- web.xml
                               |
                                --- applicationContext.xml

home.jsp
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html dir="ltr" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Spring Web!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Page URL: ${pageContext.request.requestURL}
    </body>
</html>

web.xml
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" metadata-complete="true" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<display-name>org.example.web</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/webContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

applicationContext.xml
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/page/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

On accessing http://localhost:8080/spring-web/page/home.jsp, the URL is correctly displayed as http://localhost:8080/spring-web/page/home.jsp.

Comment: I'm using Spring 3.1.1 too. What I need is an URL that is mapped by a controller. For example if you had a controller with @RequestMapping("/home") that would use page/home.jsp as a view, then using ${pageContext.request.requestURL} in that jsp would return http://localhost:8080/spring-web/page/home.jsp but in the browser it would be http://localhost:8080/spring-web/home.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approached I've had success with to build an internal link (not absolute):

Path:  `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}`
Params: `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}`

Putting those together joined by `?` to construct the current url:

```
<c:set var="currentUrl" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}?${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}"/>
```

Add additional url parameters as needed like:

```
<c:url value="${currentUrl}" var="enUrl"><c:param name="lang" value="en"/></c:url>
<c:url value="${currentUrl}" var="esUrl"><c:param name="lang" value="es"/></c:url>
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the following in a similar situation. ${currentUrl} can then be Used where needed. Needs core tag library

```
<c:url value = "" var = "currentUrl" ></c:url>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
*<% String myURI = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri").toString(); %>
                <% String[] split = myURI.split("/"); %>
                <% System.out.println("My url is-->"+ myURI
                        + "  My url splitter length --->"+split.length
                        +"last value"+split[4]);%>
<%--                <jsp:param name="split[4]" value="split[4]" /> --%>
                <c:set var="orgIdForController" value="<%= split[4] %>" />
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/supplier/add/${orgIdForController}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Add
                </a>
 - List item*
```