# How to get requestURI by using jstl in spring mvc project?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I google a lot and get a answer:

```
<c:out value="${pageContext.request.requestURI}" />
```

But I get `/myapp/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`

I want to get `/myapp/index`

How can I do that?

My project is using spring mvc.
My config in spring-mvc.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

In my /WEB-INF/views/, has a index.jsp

My Controler:

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String welcome() {
    return "index";
}
```

When I view `localhost:8088/myapp/index`, It shows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get correct current URL in JSP in Spring webapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711896/how-to-get-correct-current-url-in-jsp-in-spring-webapp)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}`

`javax.servlet.forward.*` constants retrieve information based on URI passed to `getRequestDispatcher()` (DispatcherServlet sets this attribute while handling request in the case of Spring Web MVC). But it's independent of frameworks and web containers.

As documentation says `FORWARD_SERVLET_PATH` is:

> The name of the request attribute under which the original servlet path is made available to the target of a forward

You should also remember that if the `forward()` works by calling `getNamedDispatcher()`, these attributes (there are 4 more similar attributes: `request_uri`, `context_path`, `path_info` and `query_string`) are not set because in this case the initial elements of the path does not change.

Comment: Could you explain your answer? What is this request attribute? Who sets it to the request URI and when? Is it something standard, or specific to Spring MVC, or to a specific web container? What happens if there are two forwards?

Comment: @JB Nizet No, I just found it in google to help secondflying. Please, add your detailed answer and I will immediately remove my "answer"

Comment: Oh, So quickly I get my answer, I love stackoverflow. Thank you @MaxVasileusky

Comment: @JBNizet I added some information to my answer. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MaxVasileusky: I didn't know about this attribute, and was asking you by curiosity. Your answer is also much better now. +1.